# Выполнение div с использованием задержки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый День! Как можно задать задержку для элемента div? 
В моем случае это 3 элемента, и суть проблемы заключается в том, что нужно срабатывание каждого элемента через 60 секунд.
То есть 1 галка должна быть показана через 60 секунд после загрузки страницы, 2 галка после 120 секунд, 3 после 180 секунд. Как это можно реализовать с помощью JS? Спасибо. Прикрепил код:
**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/forh19zm/)**

Comment: поставьте таймер на каждый элемент. За отрисовку галочки у Вас отвечает класс `checkmark`. Все что нужно сделать это в колбэке таймера добавлять этот класс для данного элемента

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решение, что называется - "в лоб":

```js
function ex1() {
   document.getElementById('firstArrow').style.display='inline';
}
setTimeout(ex1,60000);
function ex2() {
   document.getElementById('secondArrow').style.display='inline';
}
setTimeout(ex2,120000);
function ex3() {
   document.getElementById('thirdArrow').style.display='inline';
}
setTimeout(ex3,180000);
```

```css
    .checkmark-circle {

  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  
}
.checkmark-circle .background {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2196f3;
  position: relative;
    
}
.checkmark-circle .checkmark {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.checkmark-circle .checkmark.draw:after {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 100ms;
  -moz-animation-delay: 100ms;
  animation-delay: 100ms;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-name: checkmark;
  -moz-animation-name: checkmark;
  animation-name: checkmark;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.checkmark-circle .checkmark:after {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 25px;
  width: 27.5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
  -moz-transform-origin: left top;
  -ms-transform-origin: left top;
  -o-transform-origin: left top;
  transform-origin: left top;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 2.5px !important;
  content: '';
  left: 3px;
  top: 26px;
  position: absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 75px;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes checkmark {
  0% {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    height: 0;
    width: 37.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25.5px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    height: 40px;
    width: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="checkmark-circle"  id="firstArrow" style="display:none">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="secondArrow" style="display:none">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="checkmark-circle" id="thirdArrow" style="display:none">
   <div class="background"></div>
   <div class="checkmark draw"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну для примера можна было поставить 1-2-3, а то я смотрю, жду)))